# git - set origin from split branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git repo in the companies gitlab that has a lot of things in it.  We decided to split them into their own separate repositories. No problem,  I create a repo in gitlab,  clone it locally, copy the files over, commit and push.  Everything's fine.  Of course they want to keep the commit history for that branch.  So I do this:

```
git subtree split -P <directory_to_split> -b <target_branch>
```

Works great.  But I am having trouble figuring out how to set an upstream (origin) repo in gitlab.  I create a new repo in gitlab,  clone it locally  (it says I have cloned an empty repo, which is correct) I then do:

```
git pull <directory_of_old_repo> <target_branch>
```

And that seems to work.  But when I do a git status I get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
(use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

if I do the --unset,  well that just defeats the whole purpose and does not work.

How do I get this branch from the old repo, into its own repo with the upstream/origin as my gitlab server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Based on your command, I guess you split single directory into its own repository. Then you could consider using `git filter-branch` command, instead of `git subtree split`. You could check [this tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/).
2. And even in case of `git subtree split`, I guess you don't need to do pull from new created repo. Instead, split your repository -> so it will be stored locally -> then create remote repository -> and then push your local repo to new remote repository. Don't do pull first from your old repository - once more, you need to push your filtered/splitted repository to new remote repository. In this case, upstream will be set correctly.

Comment: so how do I set the new remote repository on the new local repo?

Comment: Check the link in my answer - you need to execute something like `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git`